# Is there an efficient way to test if an element matches a selector in Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Is there an efficient way to check if a given element matches a selector like the is()-method in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/is/)?

I have found this solution, but I think it has bad performance:

```
public static String cleanSelector(String selector) {
    return selector.replaceAll(":link|:active|:visited|:hover|:after|:focus", "");
}

public static boolean elementIs(Element elem, String selector, Element root) {
    Elements elems = root.select(cleanSelector(selector));
    return elems.contains(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the package-private `QueryParser` class:

```
Evaluator eval = QueryParser.parse(query);
boolean result = eval.matches(element.ownerDocument(), element);
```

Comment: I would also appreciate comment regarding how this answer can be used without hijacking into private Jsop packages ... otherwise it seems to be  useless.

Comment: @XtraCoder there is the `is(String cssSelector)` method now which does exactly this. But it is not yet in the latest release, but already in [this commit](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/4f707008353e272c12a7a6543d6ecfc666a7cc64).